# I don't find Oracle Sql error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I Wrote Sql

```
<insert id="insertBag" parameterType="bag">
    insert 
    into bag(p_num, p_name, p_info, p_amount, p_price, b_buy)
    values (${p_num}, ${p_name}, ${p_info}, ${p_amount}, ${p_price},${b_buy})
</insert>
```

Console Problem

```
insert      into bag(p_num, p_name, p_info, p_amount, p_price, b_buy)   
values (5, Green Chef, Narrowly taking the lead for first place is Hello Fresh! Like nearly all , 3, 9000,10)
```

> Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: Strings need to be quoted

Comment: The "SQL" you wrote is not SQL - that's XML. Show us your code that runs that "SQL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it replaces ${p_name} with Green Chef that string should be inside single quotes, right?